# Spark MLlib 0.91 org.jblas.DoubleMatrix errors

Tags: java, scala, classloader, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I'm using `spark 0.91` with `MLlib 0.91` on DSE

When trying to run the following code on standalone mode

```
val parsedData = sc.parallelize((1 to 1000).
  map {
  line =>
    LabeledPoint(0.0, Array(0.0, 0.4, 0.3))
})
val numIterations = 2
val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData, numIterations)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
    14/09/20 14:28:37 ERROR OneForOneStrategy: org.jblas.DoubleMatrix cannot be cast to org.jblas.DoubleMatrix
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jblas.DoubleMatrix cannot be cast to org.jblas.DoubleMatrix
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1$$anonfun$2.apply(GradientDescent.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1$$anonfun$2.apply(GradientDescent.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$6.apply(RDD.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$6.apply(RDD.scala:674)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.JobWaiter.taskSucceeded(JobWaiter.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:846)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.processEvent(DAGScheduler.scala:601)
```

This happens only when trying to run a standalone application. It works on spark shell (dse spark).
Any ideas?

Updates:

When I create an object on REPL the getClassLoader returns:

```
scala>  new org.jblas.DoubleMatrix().getClass().getClassLoader()
res3: ClassLoader = ModuleClassLoader:Analytics
```

But when I run in standalone mode (with spark-class) it returns

```
new org.jblas.DoubleMatrix().getClass().getClassLoader():
class= SystemClassLoader
```

Maybe this is a hint.

I use SBT to generate the jar and submit it with spark-class. Here is the configuration

```
name := "analytics"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

unmanagedJars in Compile ++=
  Attributed.blankSeq((file("./dse/lib/") * "*.jar").get)

unmanagedJars in Compile ++=
  Attributed.blankSeq((file("./dse/resources/spark/lib/") * "*.jar").get)

unmanagedJars in Compile ++=
  Attributed.blankSeq((file("./dse/resources/cassandra/lib/") * "*.jar").get)

unmanagedJars in Runtime ++=
  Attributed.blankSeq((file("./dse/resources/hadoop/") * "*.jar").get)

unmanagedJars in Runtime ++=
  Attributed.blankSeq((file("./dse/resources/hadoop/lib/") * "*.jar").get)

unmanagedJars in Compile ++=
  Attributed.blankSeq((file("./dse/resources/driver/lib/") * "*.jar").get)
```

Update 2:
Used the configuration of the dse demos to build and deploy with ant but again i face the same error

Comment: This makes me wonder whether you're sure that the Scala compiler, JVM and Spark/mllib libraries you're building the package with are the same as in your standalone Spark installation. Also, in case it helps, I'll point out that the use of org.jblas.DoubleMatrix disappears from the GradientDescent code (although not from the rest of mllib) in subsequent Spark releases -- starting with 1.0.0.

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov everything is the same. configuration (copied from sc.getConf) scala version and JMV. Also using the exact same libraries as the REPL. maybe repl is running locally and the problem is on distributed workers..

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. Given the information I gave you previously I'd be looking at upgrading Spark, which I realize you may not want to do given that you're using DSE. I do notice that DataStax have open sourced their [Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector), and it claims to be compatible with "Spark 1.0 and 1.1". Then there's the [Spark user list](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/).

Comment: You may also consider adding a "Java" tag to this question in case the classloader gurus can help.

Comment: Just to make sure - do you use `spark-class` or `dse spark-class` command to run the application?

Comment: it's dse spark-class

Answer (score 1):

This indeed seems to be a classloading problem. In particular, I believe you're hitting [this bug](https://spark-project.atlassian.net/browse/SPARK-1210), fixed in 1.0.

You can't cast an object of a class loaded by one class-loader in another class loader.

There's a small chance you may find a solution by changing the context class loader manually. It requires that you can actually get a reference to an appropriate class loader, which may or may not be possible in your case. Something like:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassloader(...)
```

But since I know nothing about DSE, I'll have to refer you to this article:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/classloading-in-dse-analytics